# Non-blocking socket loses data on Windows

Tags: c++, c, sockets, gcc

I have a non-blocking socket server which supports all connecting clients. It's using multi-threading and it's cross-compilable using GCC.

It works perfect (as I want) in Linux, but when I try to use it in Windows, when I send a 70MB of file through it, it loses around 20MB from the file.

All sockets are non-blocking, so for recv/send socket calls, I don't have check/stop. It's in a loop and it sends what it receive, it sort of acts as a Echo server, but it loses data in Windows. I'm using Winsock 2.2 in WSAStartup.

What is wrong? How can I have wait/flush send calls, but never block recv calls? (if this is the issue)

Code pieces:
How I make it non-blocking:

```
iMode = 1;
ioctlsocket(sock1,FIONBIO, &iMode);
ioctlsocket(sock2,FIONBIO, &iMode);
```

How I send/receive between two sockets:

```
for (;;)
{
    memset(buffer, 0, 8192);
    int count = recv(sock1, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    receiveResult = WSAGetLastError();
    if (receiveResult == WSAEWOULDBLOCK && count <= 0)
        continue;
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        closesocket(sock1);
        closesocket(sock2);
        return;
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        int retval = send(sock2, buffer, count, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: If the `send` and `recv` are non blocking, and you are receiving into the same buffer that you are sending, what will happen? And what about synchronization, anyway?

Comment: So you think problem is when I call send with a buffer, it doesn't copy the buffer and before sending, data gets overwritten by another recv call?

Comment: that's probably not the problem.  otherwise you'd get a lot of 0 from memset.  send should be smart enough to have an internal buffer.

Comment: And you are not checking the previous data have finished to be sent.

Comment: @ethang, exactly! I never get zeros. I just lose 20MB out of 75-80 MB file

Comment: Check `send` against `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`

Comment: the problem is probably somewhere else in your code/system... also, this thing is spinning most of the time.

Comment: @ethang, this is almost my whole code! I just have a code that creates two threads which does for loop above. sock1 and sock2 is shared. So what sock1 receives, will be sent to sock2 and what sock2 receives will be sent to sock1. It works perfect/flawless on Linux, I have problem in Windows with exact same code

Comment: @EugeneSh. and do what then? What if it was EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK?

Comment: @EugeneSh. how to check/wait for send to finish on non-blocking call?

Comment: @GeorgeLopez It means, the socket is busy sending the previous data, so you need to resend it. But it would require some bigger buffer to store the data between the iterations

Comment: Just increase send buffer size if you think it overflows.  Use SO_SNDBUF.

Comment: @ethang It will always overflow if the reception rate is higher than the sending rate. In this case the program has to buffer all (most of) of the received data.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I think the issue is probably that the data arrival rate is not uniform.  The default buffer size for Windows is 8k, so basically, every other iteration of the loop causes a hiccup.  The default buffer size for Linux is 128k...  you're right though that if the in rate is >> out rate, then you're screwed unless at some point you stop receiving data.  It also doesn't help that when there's no incoming data, the program spins and hogs up processing time.

Comment: @ethang, I think you are right. Because I was testing cross-OS. So possibly Linux sends huge data and Windows tries to get it through 8192 byte buffer and it causes problems. What do you suggest? Do you think SO_SNDBUF setting it to 128k would solve the issue? Also you said that it spins and hogs up the processing time... What's the better approach?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Do you think I should set buffer size to 128k ?

Comment: Try it.. if it will solve your problem - you are fine, unless you got asymmetric channel.

Comment: @ethang, Thank you! It worked. Issue was Windows <-> Linux socket send/receive default buffer size!

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you! It worked. Issue was Windows <-> Linux socket send/receive default buffer size

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int count = recv(sock1, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
> receiveResult = WSAGetLastError();
> if (receiveResult == WSAEWOULDBLOCK && count <= 0)
> ```

When calling `recv()` or `send()`, `WSAGetLastError()` will return a meaningful value only if -1 (`SOCKET_ERROR`) is returned, but you are also checking it when 0 is returned instead.  They do not set an error code for `WSAGetLastError()` when returning >= 0.  You need to separate those conditions.

Also, just because you have read X number of bytes does not guarantee that you will be able to send X number of bytes at one time, so you need to check `send()` for `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` until you have no more data to send.

Try something more like this:

```
bool keepLooping = true;
do
{
    int count = recv(sock1, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if (count > 0)
    {
        // data received...

        char *p = buffer;
        do
        {
            int retval = send(sock2, p, count, 0);
            if (retval > 0)
            {
                p += retval;
                count -= retval;
            }
            else if (retval == 0)
            {
                // peer disconnected...
                keepLooping = false;
            }
            else if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                // a real error occurred...
                keepLooping = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // peer is not ready to receive...
                // optionally use select() to wait here until it is...
            }
        }
        while ((count > 0) && (keepLooping));
    }
    else if (count == 0)
    {
        // peer disconnected...
        keepLooping = false;
    }
    else if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        // a real error occurred...
        keepLooping = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // no data is available for reading...
        // optionally use select() to wait here until it is...
    }
}
while (keepLooping);

closesocket(sock1);
closesocket(sock2);
return;
```